# HP DL385 G7, HP LTO 6 drive + P431 controller + 2012R2?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hp-proliant, sas, tapedrive

Im faced with the challange to making my HP385 Gen7 work with
my new HP LTO 6250 drive on a HP SAS bus card. Originally the plan was to use a SC08ge adapter with srv 2008R2 but suddenly my company changed policy to be installing srv 2012R2. I've already tried the above config with 2012R2 but the tape drive fails to install properly - (or the sc08ge card may not have the correct drivers to support tape drive) Im looking at the HP P431 controller and wonder if that could be a path to follow, replacing both the sc08ge and the internal P410i controller. Any advice on the subject would be greatly apreachiated! As I said the ultimate goal is 2012 on this G7 with a working tape drive. Brgds Tom

Comment: Can you provide some detail on "failed to install properly"?

Comment: Did this help your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The HP SC08ge adapter is just a regular old LSI external 3G SAS HBA. The driver situation is not complex, as its probably available within Windows. You should provide more detail about what you're seeing, as it normally works out of the box.

Don't replace the internal Smart Array P410 controller. It's the period-correct controller for that server.

However, you should use a 6G SAS controller for the Ultrium tape drive you're describing. All you need to do is work backwards from the [drive's specifications](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04123270.pdf). The right device for your server is a basic HP Smart Array P212 - Part #462828-B21

---

[image]